# How do I get rid of this error been trying for a day now?

Tags: c

I am trying to extract a char argument from command line using linux which i have done successfully now i want to reverse the bits of the file this code runs well when using char type but then I cant use the command line arg .
The error I get is :  `invalid operands to binary (have unsigned char * and int)`

```
printf("%d", !!((b << i) & 0x80));
```

and the line

```
temp = (b & (1 << j));
```

The code is as follows:

```
void revBits(unsigned char *b)
{
    int i;
    printf("Original Number: ");
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        printf("%d", !!((b << i) & 0x80));
    }
    printf("\n");
    unsigned int  NO_OF_BITS = sizeof(b) * 8;
    unsigned int reverse_num = 0, j, temp;

    for (j = 0; j < NO_OF_BITS; j++)
    {
        temp = (b & (1 << j));
        if(temp)
        reverse_num |= (1 << ((NO_OF_BITS - 1) - j));
    }
    printf("When reversed: %d\n",reverse_num);
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(b)` is the size of a pointer. `sizeof(*b)` is the size of a char.

Comment: You are aware that `b`  is a *pointer to* `char` and not a `char` itself?

Comment: Also the number of bits per `char` does not necessarily need to be `8` on each platform. To reflect this the C Standard defines `CHAR_BIT`.

Comment: also,  this should look like that: `temp = ((int)*b & (1 << j));`

Comment: @Serge Not necessary, and in fact redundant. Read about the standard integer promotions.

Comment: @Nemo `(int)` good for clarity, but `*b` is the main part there

Comment: -1 Maybe try and get a short description of your problem in the question title. It's useless as a resource for others otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not allowed to suppose that the number of bits in char is 8 and insert that magic constant there, as the definition of C says, it must be at least 8, but there is no upper limit, otherwise your code is not portable.

Next, sizeof(char) = 1 all the time, even when char type is implemented on 16, 64 bits, etc.  There are compilers that implement char on 64 bits, simply to avoid to to perform any kind of implicit arithmetic conversions.

The number of bits is found in `limits.h`, the macro named CHAR_BIT, in my case it is defined so by my compiler:

```
/* Number of bits in a `char'.  */
#  define CHAR_BIT  8
```

There are lots of ways to reverse a byte, here is one way (supposing your code implements it on 8 bits or 16 bits, you can keep a precomputed table):

```
char rev_byte(char byte) {
  char reversed_table = {0x00, 0x80, 0x40, ...};
  return reversed_table[byte];
}
```

Here is another way to reverse the bits in a byte `char x`, supposing as well that a byte has 8 bits. I also explained each step of the algorithm composed of a few bitwise instructions.

Suppose

> X = [ a b c d e f g h ]   **INITIALLY**

```
 /* 0x55 = ~0xAA -- 0101 0101 ~ 1010 1010 /*
 /* switch 8 groups of 1 */
 x = (x & 0x55) <<  1 | (x & 0xAA) >>  1;
```

> ==> X = [ b a d c f e h g ]

```
 /* switch 4 groups of 2 now */
 x = (x & 0x33) <<  2 | (x & 0xCC) >>  2;
```

> ==> X = [ d c b a h g f e ]

```
 /* switch 2 groups of 4 now */
 x = (x & 0x0F) <<  4 | (x & 0xF0) >>  4;
```

> ==> X = [ h g f e d c b a ]